# Solution of Differential equation $y^2+ay'^2+by''^2=c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find solution of Differential equation $$y^2+ay'^2+by''^2=c$$

I've got solution when $ay'^2+by''^2=c$,

I get 
$$y(x)= \sqrt{\frac{bc}{a^2}}\cos\left(\frac{a}{b}x+c_1\right) + c_2$$

But I have no idea about three terms $y^2+ay'^2+by''^2=c$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a general solution, but some solutions are
$$ y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{c (a - \sqrt{a^2-4b})}{2a}} \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2b}} (x - x_0)\right)$$
as well as the constants $y=\sqrt{c}$.

Comment: Thank's a lot!! It's very helpful